# Mailchimp for Magento 2.1. not showing in the backend

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, mailchimp

I have followed this tutorial https://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/mailchimp-e-commerce/ to install Mailchimp for Magento extension.

The extension is not showing. So, what have I done so far:

1. I have extracted the extension zip where I get this folders: app, js, lib, shell, skin folders and package.xml. I copy and pasted this folders and files into magento root directory.
2. Run php bin/magento setup:upgrade adn php bin/magento setup:di:compile
3. Flush the cache
   And nothing. There is no mailchimp tab on the configuration page.
   I have successfully installed some plugins already, but they had different structure, so maybe I am missing some step. 
   For the previos plugin I needed to enable the plugin via terminal:

`php bin/magento module:enable Pdf_Invoice_Plus`

The name was in registration.php file. I don't have registration.php file in this extension so I don't know the real name of this extension so I tried:

`php bin/magento module:enable mailchimp+MailChimp_For_Magento Unknown module(s): 'mailchimp+MailChimp_For_Magento'`

`php bin/magento module:enable MailChimp_For_Magento Unknown module(s): 'MailChimp_For_Magento'`

`php bin/magento module:enable Ebizmarts_MailChimp Unknown module(s): 'Ebizmarts_MailChimp'`

I am stuck. Forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 extensions always have a `registration.php` and no js, lib, shell and skin directories. You extracted a Magento 1 extension into a Magento 2 installation. The tutorial you linked also refers to Magento 1.

Magento 1 and Magento 2 are two completely different systems, you need to find a Magento 2 specific extension.

Comment: I understand that now, I quess there is not mailchimp for magento extension for magento 2. I will go back to magemonkey and try to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have downloaded magento 1 extension instead of Magento 2.

You can check this [extension](https://github.com/ebizmarts/magento2-magemonkey)

Comment: I did install this magemonkey extension, connected it to my mailchimp api, but it did not do anything. It did not sync the users, did not send to mailcimp new subscribers. I did not know what to do with it.